# How can I include a non existing value in GROUP BY with COUNT(*)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Considering this simple table called `events`

```
date       | reserved
-----------+---------
2019-11-13 | 1
2019-11-14 | 0
2019-11-15 | 1
```

Running the following query, I can retrieve the count of not reserved and reserved events:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `events` GROUP BY `reserved`
```

```
1
2
```

However, if all events are reserved I will get a single row with a single column:

```
3
```

What is the simplest way to get instead:

```
0
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are content with having both results on a single record, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    sum(reserved = 0) not_reserved,
    sum(reserved = 1) reserved
from mytable
```

This seems to me like a more sensible option, since the information it returns (in columns) is easier to understand that when provided as rows (how do you know which record correspond to the count of not reserved, especially if you don't order the results?).

Comment: You are right, this is ideal. Using expressions inside `SUM()` was a surprise, I didn't know it was possible. Thanks!

Comment: @winck: welcome! Yes in MySQL conditions as are evaluated as `0/1` when used in numeric context, that's handy...

Answer (score 3):

You can `LEFT JOIN` to a derived table of possible `reserved` values:

```
SELECT r.reserved, COUNT(e.reserved)
FROM (SELECT 0 AS reserved UNION ALL SELECT 1) r
LEFT JOIN events e ON e.reserved = r.reserved
GROUP BY r.reserved
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kskER6xK2Zbr3xRCjJD3P9/0)

Comment: This is an advanced query which produces the result I asked for (if we exclude `r.reserved` from the first `SELECT`). However, I find the answer by @GMB more appropriate in a way that I had not foreseen. Yours is much appreciated! I didn't know something like `SELECT 1` was possible. Thank you.

Comment: @winck - No worries. I included `r.reserved` in the `SELECT` so that you could tell which `COUNT` applied to which `reserved` value. As long as you order by `r.reserved` (which in MySQL is implicit if the column is in a `GROUP BY` clause), then you can don't strictly need it. I'm glad you found a solution that works better for you than what you asked for - it's one of the good things about this site that you can get different perspectives on a problem.